# Integrate SSRS with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

Is there a way to integrate SSRS with Visual Studio 2010?

If not, is there any other way to use SQL Server Reporting Services in my projects, when using SQL Server 2012, MS Report Builder 3.0 and Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Could you please explain you question a bit more?
What would you like to integrate?

btw: SQL Server 2012 R2 does not exist!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using SQL Server 2008 R2 and to start the tool you are going to use to create reports in SSRS, you to go Start> All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 > SQL Server Development Studio. There you can create projects with the Report Wizard to use in SSRS. You need to have Reporting Services service started and other stuff, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was originally asked, MS has released [SQL Server Data Tools – Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) which allows you to create SSRS reports from VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use reporting services reports within a winform/webform application you can do this using the report viewer control: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

You cannot create SSRS 2008/2008 R2 reports in Visual Studio 2010, you need to use Visual Studio 2008/Business Intelligence Development Studio or Report Builder 3.0.

Only SQL Server 2012 supports development of SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2010.